# Example of L2 function with separated from zero increment integral

Tags: functional-analysis

Do there exists a function $f: \exists \varepsilon_0 > 0, \forall h>0, f \in L_2[0,1],$ such that $\|f\|_2=1$, but 
$$
\int\limits_{[0,1-h]}|f(t+h)-f(t)|\mu(dt) > \varepsilon_0\:?
$$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let us see that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}|f(t+h)-f(t)|dt\rightarrow 0,~~~~h\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
Let $\varphi\in C[0,1]$ such that $\|f-\varphi\|_{L^{1}[0,1]}<\epsilon$, then 
\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{1}|f(t+h)-f(t)|dt\\
&\leq\int_{h}^{1+h}|f(t)-\varphi(t)|+\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)-\varphi(t)|dt+\int_{0}^{1}|\varphi(t+h)-\varphi(t)|dt.
\end{align*}
Note that we extend canonically $f(t)=0$ and $\varphi(t)=0$ for those $t\notin[0,1]$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}|f(t+h)-f(t)|dt\leq 2\|f-\varphi\|_{L^{1}[0,1]}+\int_{0}^{1}|\varphi(t+h)-\varphi(t)|dt,
\end{align*}
which can be controlled by arbitrary small by applying Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to the right-sided integral since $\varphi$ is continuous.

Now we have the inequalities that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}|f(t+h)-f(t)|dt\geq\int_{0}^{1-h}|f(t+h)-f(t)|>\epsilon,
\end{align*}
we let $h\downarrow 0$ to get a contradiction.