# Show that $\lim_{t\to0} \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)[f(x)-f(x+t)]dx = 0$. Does my solution work?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $g$ be a bounded measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $$\lim_{t\to0} \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)[f(x)-f(x+t)]dx = 0.$$

(Taken from Royden, 4th edition, #47 (part ii), chapter 4)

Part one of this question asked me to show that if $f$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x+t)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx,$$ which I proved with a  boot strapping argument.

Royden gives a hint for this second part using uniform integrability, and the solution to a different exercise in the book. I'm wondering if I can do the following instead;

Since $g$ is bounded, we can say there is some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $-M \leq g(x) \leq M$. Then, by monotonicity of the integral, we have  $$-M\int_{\mathbb{R}}[f(x)-f(x+t)]dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)[f(x)-f(x+t)]dx \leq M\int_{\mathbb{R}}[f(x)-f(x+t)]dx,$$

Using linearity of the integral, we then have 
$$-M(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+t)dx) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)[f(x)-f(x+t)]dx \leq M(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+t)dx)$$

And by the equality of the translates (which is true for all $t$), we thus have $$0\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)[f(x)-f(x+t)]dx \leq 0.$$

Thus $\lim_{t\to0} \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)[f(x)-f(x+t)]dx = 0$

This seems to me like it should work, but the hint provided in Royden seems to require some stuff that's more high powered, so it's got me wondering whether or not this simple approach is valid.

If it's not valid, could someone point out which step in my argument is wrong?

Any and all thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438386/example-of-l2-function-with-separated-from-zero-increment-integral

Comment: The integrnad imight not be nonnegative so you might not have the monotonicity

Answer (score 1):

Arctic has pointed out the mistake.

Rather, we can do like
\begin{align*}
\left|\int g(x)(f(x)-f(x+t))dx\right|&\leq\int|g(x)(f(x)-f(x+t))|dx\\
&\leq M\int|f(x)-f(x+t)|dx.
\end{align*}
The rest can be done exactly like my answer in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438386/example-of-l2-function-with-separated-from-zero-increment-integral).

The philosophy is that, we hope that $f(x+t)\rightarrow f(x)$ as $t\rightarrow 0$ and then apply Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, the point is that, $f$ may not be a good function to have the pointwise convergence, so we approximate it by a good one.