# $g_n(x)=f(x+1/n)$ converges to $f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This is a question from my previous homework, which I didn't do and want a solution now since I am reviewing for my final.

"Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that  $g_n(x)=f(x+1/n)$ converges to $f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$"

I could not do it before since it LOOKS obvious. Since the $g_n(x)$ LOOKS LIKE it converges pointwise to $f$ so it gives me such an impression. I am so stuck with this idea that I do not know how to approach properly.

Of course, converge almost everywhere does not implies convergence in $L^1$. So in a way my approach is wrong. Can you help?

Comment: How do you get pointwise convergence?

Comment: oh right, I clearly messed up with continuity and convergent in L^1. I will edit it now

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438386/example-of-l2-function-with-separated-from-zero-increment-integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is a known fact that $$\lim_{t \to 0}\int|f(x+t)-f(x)|dx \to 0$$ for Lebesgue integrable functions.

This can be proved by approximation with simple functions.

So use this with $t_n=\frac{1}{n} \to 0$

Comment: this sure is fast. May I ask where can I find a proof for this result?

Comment: @MarcosGNeil this is a standrd approximation argument..you can find it also in this site and in many textbooks or lecture notes.